# Error "field has incomplete type"

Tags: c++, opencv, wrapper, shared-ptr

I'm trying to write IplImage wrapper.

Here is my code:

```
class DrawingDetector
{
public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<IplImage> ipl_image_ptr_t;

    DrawingDetector(){}
    DrawingDetector::DrawingDetector(IplImage* img) : m_image(img, ipl_deleter){}

private:

    static void ipl_deleter( IplImage* ipl_img )
    {
        if( ipl_img )
        {
            cvReleaseImage( &ipl_img );
        }
    }

    ipl_image_ptr_t m_image; // compiler error "field ‘m_image’ has incomplete type"

};
```

I've got the following compling error "field ‘m_image’ has incomplete type".
My compiler is gcc 4.4.

Why I can't create an empty shared_ptr?

Comment: Can you add your includes ?

Comment: Just a sidenote: Your constructor takes just a plain pointer, while inside your class you take ownership of the `IplImage` with a `shared_ptr` and a custom deleter. That means you are separating construction of the `IplImage` from its deletion, but both should be consistent. Solution: make the constructor parameter a `shared_ptr` itself. That way you leave it to the caller how the `IplImage` is constructed *and destroyed*. Further more it states explicitly in you class' interface, that you take shared ownership of the image, which is a good thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the field has type `boost::shared_ptr<IplImage>`, it seems you haven't included `boost/shared_ptr.hpp` and/or the header defining `IplImage`. For `IplImage` it could be sufficient to provide only a forward declaration.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler doesn't see the boost shared ptr or IplImage definition. You should include the corresponding header

Answer (score 2):

"Incomplete type" means a type that has been declared but not defined. This probably means that you're not including `boost/shared_ptr.hpp`, which provides the definition.